# Too few arguments to function App\Policies\QuotePolicy::view() in Laravel

Tags: laravel, middleware

I am using middelware to call policies on a certain model:

This is the concerned method of the policy:

the first argument which is the user is passed in the arguments array but the second argument is not retrieved by the policy view method.

How can I solve this issue, please?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... are you trying to use the `quote` route parameter for the authorization of the `view` ability? ... if you are not planning on using an instance of that resource (which is what the way you are calling `can` would imply) you would have that policy method not take an argument for the resource since one won't be passed

Comment: i need to pass an instance of Quote model to the  policy method , thanks for your comment

Comment: I am assuming you want the route parameter `quote` to be used as the resource to check against?

Answer (score 0):

The `public function view(User $user, Quote $quote)` expects the 2nd argument to be the object of Quote, but you're passing a name of the class (string Quote::class) instead. Try changing `Quote::class` in your code to `'quote'` (same name as the variable in the URL), that should pass the object.

Answer (score 0):

The `view` gate is for viewing a specific item. As such, it requires passing a specific `Quote` model, not the class itself.

If you want to check the user's ability to view *any* of this sort of item, use the `viewAny` check instead.